# Ipython console in Spyder not using environment defined Python version

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython, spyder

Os is Linux Mint. Installed anaconda and created a new env with `conda create --name tf1 python=3.7 spyder tensorflow-gpu=1.13`. Installed fine without an error. But the spyder console is working on `python 3.8` instead of `3.7`. Therefore I can't import tensorflow since it supports `3.7` at best. In Windows installation I don't face with such an issue.

Comment: Try this: `conda deactivate`, `conda activate foo_env`, `python -V`

Comment: Well it worked but what was the trick here? Did I had to deactivate and activate?

Comment: You created the virtual environment but were not using it in your CLI.